# Roles and Responsibilites in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am creating the roles and responsibilities the code has to be followed:

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('admin.sidebar', function ($view) {
$moduleRs = DB::table('users')
    ->join('permissions','users.role', '=', 'permissions.role_id') 
    ->select('users.role as usersrole','permissions.role_id as role_id','permissions.module_name as module_name')
    ->where('users.role', '=', \Auth::user()->role)
    ->get();
   // dd($moduleRs[0]->module_name);
   $moduleData = null;

    if ( count($moduleRs) > 0 ) {
     $result = [];
      foreach($moduleRs as $row){
        if(!isset($result[$row->role_id])) {
            $result[$row->role_id] = array(
                'role_id' => $row->role_id,
                'module_name' => [$row->module_name],
        );
        }else{
            $result[$row->role_id]['module_name'] = array_merge($result[$row->role_id]['module_name'], [$row->module_name] );
           }
    }


    $data=$moduleRs[0]->module_name;
    dd($data);
    $splittedstring[]=explode(" ,",$data);
    //dd($splittedstring);
    foreach ($splittedstring as $key => $value) {
    echo "  '.$value.'<br>";
    }  
} 

$view->with('moduleData', $moduleData);
});

 }
```

In the above code when i can use dd($data) it can display the id of permissions of the user.But when hide the dd($data) means it couldn't make the result as well.Please provide an idea.

[image]

when i can hide dd(...) it shows like this found above screen shots..

```
when i put dd($splittedstring) means it shows this found below

   array:3 [▼
   0 => "0"
   1 => "4"
   2 => "5"
   ]
```

This is module found at the below cases of screen shots i can store this module in modules table field name of module

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

this is the permission form found below which has to fetch the module name from modules table and store this value to permissions table field name of module_name but it is a integer not a string this is a foreign key..
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

and shows in a view display as like as follows..Here Role 1=>Super Admin 0=>Admin... i can make permission admin as 0=>Dashboard,4=>Employee,5=>Lead..when i login as a admin i can view only Dashboard,Employee and Lead only

Permission's create.blade.php

```
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Create New Permission</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <a href="{{ url('/permission/permission') }}" title="Back"><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Back</button></a>
                    <br />
                    <br />

                    @if ($errors->any())
                        <ul class="alert alert-danger">
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    @endif

                    {!! Form::open(['url' => '/permission/permission', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'files' => true]) !!}

                    @include ('permission.permission.form')

                    {!! Form::close() !!}

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Permission's form.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('role_id') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
{!! Form::label('role_id', 'Role', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) 
!!}
<div class="col-md-6">  

    {!! Form::select('role_id',($role),null,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
     {!! $errors->first('role_id', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
   </div>
</div><div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('module_name') ? 'has-error':     ''}}">
   {!! Form::label('module_name', 'Module', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-
   label']) !!}
   <div class="col-md-6"> 
   {!! Form::select('module_name[]',($module), null, ['class' => 'form-
  control','multiple' => true]) !!} 
  {!! $errors->first('module_name', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') 
   !!}


   </div>

  </div> 

   <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
      {!! Form::submit(isset($submitButtonText) ? $submitButtonText : 
      'Create', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!} 
   </div>
</div>
```

permissionController.php  store and create function

```
  public function create()
{
    $role = \DB::table('roles')->pluck('name');

    $module = \DB::table('modules')->pluck('module'); 
   return view('permission.permission.create',array('role'=>$role,'module'=>$module)); 

}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $requestData = $request->all();
    $news = $request->input('module_name');
    $news = implode(',', $news);
    $input = $request->except('module_name');
   //Assign the "mutated" news value to $input
        $input['module_name'] = $news;
    Permission::create($input);

    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Permission added!');

    return redirect('permission/permission');

}

 public function show($id)
{
    $permission = Permission::findOrFail($id);

    return view('permission.permission.show', compact('permission'));
}
```

show.blade.php

```
  <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Permission {{ $permission->id }}</div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <a href="{{ url('/permission/permission') }}" title="Back"><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Back</button></a>
                    <a href="{{ url('/permission/permission/' . $permission->id . '/edit') }}" title="Edit Permission"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</button></a>
                    {!! Form::open([
                        'method'=>'DELETE',
                        'url' => ['permission/permission', $permission->id],
                        'style' => 'display:inline'
                    ]) !!}
                        {!! Form::button('<i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete', array(
                                'type' => 'submit',
                                'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs',
                                'title' => 'Delete Permission',
                                'onclick'=>'return confirm("Confirm delete?")'
                        ))!!}
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                    <br/>
                    <br/>

                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-borderless">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th><td>{{ $permission->id }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr><th> Role </th><td> {{ $permission->role_id }} </td></tr><tr><th> Module </th><td> {{ $permission->module_name }} </td></tr>
                            </tbody> 

                        </table>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: **Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging.** If you are asked for code or additional information, edit it into your question. I already cleaned up a bunch of comments here yesterday, and today there were 50+ more added. That is not acceptable. This is not a chat room.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `create` function in `permissioncontroller` like:

**permissionController.php**

```
public function create()
{
  $role = \DB::table('roles')->pluck('name');

  $module = \DB::table('modules')->get();

  $arrModule = array();

  foreach($module as $modules){

    $arrModule[$modules->id] = $modules->module;

  }

  return view('permission.permission.create',array('role'=>$role,'module'=>$arrModule)); 

}
```

**Updated Answer**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $permission = Permission::findOrFail($id);

    $permissionModule =explode(",",$permission->module);



    $module = \DB::table('modules')->get();

    $arrPermissionModule = array();

    foreach($module as $modules){

      if(in_array($modules->id,$permissionModule)){

        $arrPermissionModule[$modules->id] = $modules->module;

      }

    }

    return view('permission.permission.show', compact('permission','arrPermissionModule'));
}
```

**Show.blade.php**

```
<div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Permission {{ $permission->id }}</div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <a href="{{ url('/permission/permission') }}" title="Back"><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Back</button></a>
                    <a href="{{ url('/permission/permission/' . $permission->id . '/edit') }}" title="Edit Permission"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</button></a>
                    {!! Form::open([
                        'method'=>'DELETE',
                        'url' => ['permission/permission', $permission->id],
                        'style' => 'display:inline'
                    ]) !!}
                        {!! Form::button('<i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete', array(
                                'type' => 'submit',
                                'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs',
                                'title' => 'Delete Permission',
                                'onclick'=>'return confirm("Confirm delete?")'
                        ))!!}
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                    <br/>
                    <br/>

                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-borderless">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th><td>{{ $permission->id }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr><th> Role </th><td> {{ $permission->role_id }} </td></tr>
                                <tr><th> Module </th>
                                  <td> 
                                    @foreach($arrPermissionModule as $arrPermissionModules)
                                      {{ $arrPermissionModules }} 
                                    @endforeach
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody> 

                        </table>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```